# Re-Subscribing a Mobile Subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

If a Subscriber receives an SMS message from MobileConnect and replies with an opt-out keyword (e.g. 'STOP'), then they are automatically suppressed from receiving future SMS messages.

However, is there a way to re-subscribe an unsubscribed mobile subscriber if they want to opt-in again?

The only way we've been able to do this previously is to open a support case.

Comment: Good question, I would like to know this too.

Comment: Hello Eliot, did you find a solution for this issue ? I'm facing the problem. I have tried this API [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/using-the-mobileconnect-api.htm) but it doesn't work :/

Comment: I'm told that you should be able to simply import a list to MobileConnect Contacts and set the status to Active. I haven't tried that though. If you want to give that a go and it works for you, please post your answer to this question.

Comment: I have already tried this but it only change the status of the subscriber. But he still opted out for the Keyword :/

Answer (score 2):

The only reliable way I've found to manage this is to never actually unsubscribe them from receiving messages. So, whenever a subscriber texts STOP, I present them with the standard STOP language but I have a script text join in the background with an additional keyword that lets the JOIN keyword know not to send a message to the user.

I'll then update this records mobile-opt-in flag in Sales Cloud to false inside that same script rather than managing that state in Marketing Cloud. If you weren't using the connector then I'd imagine you could just write to a master status DE and do lookups on that data extension when generating your mobile campaigns (or when in journeys) to manage the users status rather than having the system deal with this.

Comment: Jason, do you have example script for the solution you outlined? I'm in the same boat and your solution sounds like exactly what would remedy it.

Comment: Dave, this one would require a full post to outline the solution since it involves multiple keywords and the logic interplay between the two. The basics are to have your STOP keyword use the UpdateSingleSalesforceObject ampscript function to change the user's opt-in status in SF, and then use the queueMO REST API endpoint to text "JOIN STOP" to your Join keyword. Then just parse the keywords coming into you JOIN keyword to check for the presence of STOP and, if it's there, output a "thanks for unsubbing" response otherwise serve the standard JOIN response.

Comment: It should be noted that Salesforce Support will recommend that you never use this implementation and will not provide any support to the above solution since it circumvents their standard opt-in/out system. Your on your own if you follow this path unfortunately, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

contact builder mobile connect and use phone number to search the contact then go to their profile, mobile tab, and opt them out manually